# Not able to install packages in PyCharm on windows 10

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, windows-10, virtualenv

I am using PyCharm on Windows 10 with Python 3.9. For last couple of days I am not able to install any packages (Earlier it was working fine) and getting the error below:

```
    (venv) PS D:\projects\Python\mantis> pip install flask
    WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILE
    D] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1123)'))': /simple/flask/
    WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILE
    D] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1123)'))': /simple/flask/
    Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/flask/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /
    simple/flask/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1123)'))
    ) - skipping
    ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement flask (from versions: none)
    ERROR: No matching distribution found for flask
    Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /si
    mple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1123)'))) - 
    skipping
```

I tried lot many solutions, but no success.

Answer (score 0):

To me this looks like you have some sort of HTTPS Interception, if possible disable HTTPS Interception or add the self signed certificate to trusted certificates.

Comment: How to do this? I am windows user

Comment: Usually this is due to a firewall or proxy, have there been any recent changes to how you connect to the internet? (since it was working fine before, maybe it was that you were at your house and now you are at work or connecting over a VPN).

Comment: Yes I am on VPN and may be some settings at office end

Comment: Your office would be using https intercept to decrypt your traffic to scan it. Just get I.T. to add their certificate to your trust certificates on your PC.

Alternatively just disconnect from VPN and install packages you need.

Comment: Not sure. using $ pip install --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host pypi.python.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org <package_name> works but from Pycharm Package manager it doesn't

Comment: The problem is that you have a self signed Certificate Authority (which is most likely TLS inspection by the company firewall, this allows them to incept traffic that is meant to be encrypted in transit) The CA is creating certificates for every https connection to replace every valid certificate with a self signed certificate. 

By using the --trusted-host option, you are just telling pip to ignore that your computer is saying this isn't safe.

The best solution is to add this certificate authority to the trusted list in certmgr, IT can push this out using group policy.

Comment: Alternatively you can go File->Settings->Project->Python Interpreter. Then click on the + find the package that you want to install tick the options and put in the "--trusted-host <hostname>" details here.

Remember this isn't recommend as it's manual(and project specific), reduces your security as you are disabling all TLS checks.

Comment: Thanks for detailed elaboration